# How about a "Decadist" gold badge? Just like the "Yearling" silver badge?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

What I suggest is that a programmer who is actively participating in this platform for a full decade should be awarded with such a little symbolic award. The 10th anniversary would just be a good point to launch it.

What do you think?

Comment: Maybe "Decadent" ;-)

Comment: Even better ..

Comment: Finally, something productive and easy to implement :D

Comment: A decade seems a bit long, but then again there are already [8000+](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/903892) people who would classify (5697 if we limit it to those with at least 1k reputation, 1731 for 10k).

Comment: @Dukeling How do you measure their activity? I think a possibility would be (it is *not* a suggestion) to check, if the user has created at least a single DB entity (post or comment) in all the years.

Comment: @peterh The yearling badge is defined by "Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation.". We could make it "Active member for 10 years, earning at least 200 reputation in each." Should it be a requirement for the years to be consecutive?

Comment: @Blackbam Yes, I think also this is a very nice idea. I wrote a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/903998/) for these people. It is not exact (for example, it can't count bounties), but there is not too much difference from the reality. They are around 6625. Quite a lot!

Comment: Cool, I'll be eligible for this new badge in 5 months ;-)

Comment: @peterh I don't know how yearling works exactly, but I'd say just go with how that works. If it's more complicated than this, I'm inclined to say we just check if they were online at all during that time (and they got some reputation over the whole period). I don't really see the benefit of complicating it, which would in the process exclude just a few people, who may be very unhappy about that (especially if they marginally miss(ed) the requirement in some year or another).

Comment: @Dukeling I think it is a strong argument, maybe the rules could be made more fluid in this sense. For example, 2000 rep should have been earned in the last years, but it is enough if only in 7 years had been got the 200. Or some similar.

Comment: ...Or it could just be a silver badge. Its not exactly *hard* to get. \*Shrug\*

Comment: @peterh - *How do you measure their activity?* - you could measure it by checking who has accumulated 10 "Yearling" badges.  Or, 10 Yearling badges **in consecutive years** if you prefer, to make it harder.

Comment: A bit over five years ago, I asked on MSE (or what's now MSE) about [Any thoughts on a semidecadian badge for people with five years of service and an average of N points per year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196659/any-thoughts-on-a-semidecadian-badge-for-people-with-five-years-service-and-an-a)  It wasn't accepted at the time.  I still think that the idea was valid, although I have no particular attachment to the suggested name — I had to come up with something to ask the question, that's all.

Comment: @dbc Thanks, I've thought on it. But I don't know, when the "Yearling" badge was inserted into the system. As far I know, the 2008 version of the site was yet very different. And getting badges for badges seems unrealistic to me that the SE would find it convincing. Maybe if all tenth "yearling" badge would be a golden "decadist" one? So, the consecutivity criteria would be completely eliminated.

Answer (score 41):

A better name would be [Denarian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denarian):

> One who is between the age of 10 and 19, inclusive.

To be followed by Vicenarian, Tricenarian, etc.  (Also, fits with Yearling = one year old).

Comment: +1 for also sounding like it could be the name of an alien race from star trek

Comment: Isn't that the name of those demons from the Dresden Files?

Comment: These words look like Latin (or modern Latin, like French or Italian)

Comment: More [like money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denarius).

Comment: prefer 'glutton for punishment' myself. :)